# Composer и stable версии

Tags: php, github, composer, packagist

Веду небольшой пакет на `github` (оформлен в `packagist`), после создания релиза `2.0.0` - он показал его как стабильный. Потом, я нашел серьезную ошибку в реализации, и на сколько я понимаю систему версионности, т.к. API не менялось, после коммита создал релиз `2.0.1` (т.е. произошли исправления, не затрагивающие API), но `packagist` так и считает версию `2.0.0` стабильной. Как перевести его на новую версию?

**UPDATE:**

```
{
    "name": "name/name",
    "description": "Desctiption",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "AuthorName",
            "email": "email@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.7.*",
        "satooshi/php-coveralls": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4" : {
            "NameSpace\\" : "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а что у вас прописано в composer.json?

Comment: @korytoff, обновил

Comment: А composer.json который используется для загрузки этого расширения?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, при чем тут он)

Comment: Вы при обновлении своего расширения так или иначе обращаетесь напрямую к своему репозиторию на `github`. `packagist` используется только для получения абсолютного url вашей библиотеки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `composer.json` на `github` можете добавить `version: "2.0.1"` и еще новый тег `v2.0.1`. На `packagist` есть кнопка для обновления информации.

### UPD

Так же вы можете создать новую ветку `2.0` в которой вести правки минорной версии и `Packagist` сразу их подцепит. [Дока по тегам](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#specifying-the-version) для композера

### UPD 2

По наставлению @Etki – оказывается в `composer.json` действительно лучше не указывать версию. [Документация](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version)

Соответственно добавление тега и/или ветки с версией будет достаточно.

### UPD 3

Как выяснилось, проблема была на стороне https://poser.pugx.org, который кешировал информацию о пакете.

Comment: у меня через вебхуки, так что кнопка не нужна (автоматом обновляется)

Comment: @A1essandro тогда я не понимаю, где у вас что не обновляется

Comment: https://github.com/A1essandro/Diamond-And-Square - вот репозиторий, в релизах есть версия `2.0.1`, а https://poser.pugx.org/ который через `packagist` работает, показывает `2.0.0`

Comment: @A1essandro у меня все по тегам отрабатывает как часы, главное в теге четко придерживаться стандартов `v2.0.1` и все должно быть нормально

Comment: в composer.json не стоит писать версию вообще, это прямо в документации указывается

Comment: @Etki странно. А можно ссылку?

Comment: @A1essandro кстати у вас там версия стоит нужна – http://joxi.ru/J2b5Rp5HY8jVm6

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version

Comment: @Etki да, действительно. Спасибо, буду в курсе

Comment: Всем спасибо за отзывы. Решилось. Видимо poser у себя где-то кэширует, на довольно продолжительное время.